# 400 Bad Request only on Chrome 89.0.4389.116

Tags: node.js, google-chrome

For our application we extract decoded params from the encoded url, like "Café Boss", and perform an api call to our backend to fetch the data for that restaurant.

This all has been working perfectly for the past year, but since this week we seem to have trouble with restaurant names that have special characters like "é". We see a "400 bad request" error and "HttpErrorResponse" in the inspect module of the browser.

This only happens in production with Chrome 89.0.4389.116 and works fine on older version and other browsers. When I run the same code in localhost it runs perfectly. I console logged the params we extract, and in all browsers they are exactly the same. The request headers are also exactly the same.

Since this seems to be a problem **solely exclusive to the newest version of Chrome**, I believe this is a bug within Chrome itself. However, I may be wrong and I'm hoping someone had the same problem and can offer a solution.

Comment: have you tried performing the same request in Postman or another browser?

Comment: Yes. Works fine on older Chrome versions, Firefox and Postman.

Problem also occurs on other devices with same Chrome version.

Comment: Have you checked any logs from the backend api ?

Comment: I debugged a bit further. I overlooked the fact the the 400 status is called when the reastaurant name in the header is null or undefined.

When I inspect the Network calls in Chrome, it shows that the restaurant name is added to the headers. In the backend it arrives as null/undefined.

This is quite strange as it only happens in this certain version of Chrome.

Comment: What's even stranger, is that I also tested the same restaurant on our dev servers. app-dev.com/Caf%C3%A9%20Boss/Lounge%201 instead of app.com/Caf%C3%A9%20Boss/Lounge%201 . In the dev url it works perfect. In our production it throws a 400. And it's exactly the same code, only a different node environment.

Comment: I changed the 'é' to a regular 'e'. It works that way. But sadly the customer doesn't want that, as they would need to re-print a lot of QR stickers. It really must be a special character bug with that version of Chrome, I'll submit a bug report soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bypassed this problem by encoding the restaurant name with encodeURI before passing it to the headers and by decoding it in the backend.